# How to install Node.js on CentOS without sudo permissions

Tags: node.js, centos, centos7, sudo

I have a linux server that I can access with ssh to my own space at my university. I could create a virtual environment and install whatever I want to it with Python.

Now I want to install Node.js and run it there even if I log off. Kinda using college's computing power for my discord bot..

I don't have sudo permissions obviously is this possible if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try nvm https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
If that doesn’t help, you is always free to ask yow techas or sys admin to install it for you, but nvm should be enough

Comment: Excellent! Any chance you also know how to keep Node application online even after logging off?

Comment: yes, there are some options, but the one I use is pm2. watch this from point 3 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-centos-7